# KeyEventArgs event not working

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Why doesn't that work in VS 2010? I press "a" in the form after clicking on it, and nothing happens.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.A)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A");
        }
    }
```

Comment: "doesn't that work" what you mean?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When you type "doesn't work" or "error" or "access violation", the *very next thing* you should type is exactly what that means. In the case of "doesn't work", you should explain *how* it doesn't work like you'd expect. If you get an error, post the *exact* error message you get. We can't see your screen or read your mind, so we only know what you decide to tell us in your question. If you want us to help you, please be specific and provide details. Thanks. :-)

Comment: There about 10 reasons why "it doesn't work".  Number eleven is that the form can't get the focus when it has any child controls that can get the focus.

Answer (score 1):

Use KeyPreview on the form in question:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyPreview = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form probably doesn't have focus when you press the key.

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key
>   events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.

```
this.KeyPreview = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, I added that. But still, when i click on form and press A key nothing happens. I just started to learn, the tutorial said nothing about this.KeyPreview = true;

Answer (score 0):

Have you done

```
KeyPreview = true;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

is the KeyEventHandler assigned?

```
KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
```